# How to fix internet connection working only on Microsoft Edge?

Tags: windows-10, internet-connection

### The issue:

My computer was working properly and all of a sudden it seemed there was no internet at all, for example when trying to access something on the internet in Firefox I have either "Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site." or "Corrupted Content Error", I have Outlook asking me for my messaging password again and again but never logging in, basically any application that needs internet has connection error… except for Microsoft Edge, on which I'm able to write this issue.

What is Strange too is that I have a Linux running under VirtualBox that has no internet issue at all. Coworkers have same Windows installed with same updates but no internet issue.

Using wireshark we can see http traffic when going to google.fr for example from Microsoft Edge but nothing at all from Firefox, it seems request goes nowhere.

Also I can ping for example google.fr from a command prompt.

### What we  tried:

- sfc /scannow
- Setting fix IP instead of get from DHCP
- A fix that seemed to work for everyone: https://thegeekpage.com/troubleshoot-microsoft-edge-access-internet-windows-10/ (we had "Resetting , failed." "Access is denied." issue on ip reset command that we fixed with this: https://davidvielmetter.com/tricks/netsh-int-ip-reset-says-access-denied/)
- Use Windows 10 repair tools
- Disable firewall/antivirus
- Check proxy configuration on applications (Firefox and Edge at least)

### Conclusion:

After our company IT and I took hours to trying to fix it without success, now we will completely reinstall Windows 10 on my computer since I need to have it to continue working as soon as possible, but still, even if I will then not be able to say if an answer works for me, I ask the question in case somebody has fallen in the same issue and be able to fix it with another solution that which we tried. And (hopefully not) if my computer falls again in this issue I'll be able to try it.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like Edge is configured to use the proxy that is required and Firefox isn't.  However, if you are no longer going to be able to confirm a solution exists, it's going to be impossible to answer this question.

Comment: I agree (+1). Almost certainly proxy. Failing that, a per program firewall rule

Comment: Thanks, I was just coming to enrich answer since I forgot some thinks we tried (both proxy and firewall are part of them), I update my answer in a second. Edit: moreover, if it was proxy, why it has been working for days/weeks/months and then begin to fail all of a sudden for all apps except Edge without changing anything ?